# Mismatch when converting an char array into ULLs and vice versa in C

Tags: c, arrays, endianness, unsigned

I have a huge 2048-bit string (string 'encrypted' of length 256 in example) it can take random values meaning NOT necessary ASCII values.
My goal is to chunk it into unsigned long long (ULL) values to be used for some custom operation (which operates only on ULL) and restore back the original string from the chunked ULLs. (My computer is little endian and 64-bit)

I have the following code where my goal is to make encrypted2 match encrypted. However the below code is incorrect. I think it messes with endian-ness and so I do not get back the original string contents. Can anyone help me fix the issue or suggest a good work around?

```
unsigned long long val, longInt;
char buffer[9];
buffer[8] = '\0';
char byteArray[9];
byteArray[8] = '\0';

for(chunk = 0; chunk < 32; chunk++) {
    strncpy(buffer, encrypted + 8 * chunk, 8);
    val = (uint64_t)buffer[0] << 56 |
          (uint64_t)buffer[1] << 48 |
          (uint64_t)buffer[2] << 40 |
          (uint64_t)buffer[3] << 32 |
          (uint64_t)buffer[4] << 24 |
          (uint64_t)buffer[5] << 16 |
          (uint64_t)buffer[6] << 8  |
          (uint64_t)buffer[7];
    vals[chunk] = val;
}

for (chunk = 0; chunk < 32; chunk++) {
    longInt = vals[chunk];
    byteArray[0] = (char)((longInt >> 56) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[1] = (char)((longInt >> 48) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[2] = (char)((longInt >> 40) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[3] = (char)((longInt >> 32) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[4] = (char)((longInt >> 24) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[5] = (char)((longInt >> 16) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[6] = (char)((longInt >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byteArray[7] = (char)((longInt) & 0xFF);
    strncpy(encrypted2 + chunk * 8, byteArray, 8);
}
```

Please help me match encrypted and encrypted2 in my above code.

**Example** input for encrypted[256] would be

```
C���EK�U�ߺA#|��-��fDJ�J
ڰ���.�2(��+<��^���r0��v�.�'��GR�M��,52�����{r7RPqRD1�ú
                                                          ��q4�iP��E�Cm��$
���Z�+�Q��&Xx�F0� X#(���N���6r�R�`�]"gvV2[)��75��)
```

Comment: If you are dealing with binary data use `memcpy` instead of `strncpy`. `strncpy` will stop at null byte.

Comment: use memcpy instead of strncpy. strncpy copy until 0 byte

Comment: `(uint64_t)buffer[0]` wont work for negative values. `buffer` should also be unsigned. Some variable declarations are missing in your example. Can you post [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I changed to memcpy instead of strncpy. Still, I am NOT able to get the expected results

Comment: @Banthar - You are right. I fixed it converting the buffer to unsigned char

Answer (score 2):

While you're working with `char` arrays, you're not working with *strings*: you should be using `memcpy` rather than `strncpy`.

Comment: .. by turning away from using the `str*()`-functions there also is no need for the additional `0`-termination any more, as well as for `buffer` being 9 but 8 bytes long.

Comment: I changed strncpy to mempy and checked. No luck -- the issue still persists.